# How to read csv content in columns

Tags: powershell

How would you read a csv column using  get-content?

Comment: While your wanting to help the community is admirable. `Import-CSV` and `Where-Object` are both well documented. Are you having an issue? Otherwise i dont see what value this adds to the community. A good chunk of your code could be simplified as well.

Comment: You need to edit this to make it fit the Stack Overflow format. Rephrase your post in the form of a question, and then provide your  script as a separate answer. Normally I'd edit for you, but since I don't want take credit for your work I need to wait for your do this for yourself. Until then, I voted to close.

Comment: Corrected. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Matt it's not code. it's a script. http://www.naelshawwa.com/scripting-coding-programming/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the past week I needed to read columns in a csv file and had a little bit of trouble. Then I found out about the import-csv which reads the head row. So I created a script and wanted to give to others so they could use it as well.

This script reads the rows of a csv file containing "IP" , "Exploitability" , "OS" , and "Severity" then it parses the file using the Where-Object method like this:

```
Where-Object {$_.Severity -eq 5 -or $_.Severity -eq 4 -and $_.OS -like "Windows*" }
```

here is the script- modify and please enjoy:

```
#load assembly for file dialog box
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") | Out-Null;


#File dialog box to browse to file.
function diagbx()
{
     $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
     $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
     $OpenFileDialog.filter = "Comma Separated Value (*.csv)|*.csv
     $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog()
     $OpenFileDialog.filename
}

#get the results of the function
$file = diagbx;

#Check to see if diag was cancled.
if ($file[0] -eq "Ok")
{
    #get the content of the file
    $content = Import-Csv $file[1]

    #create empty array variable to be accessed outside of conditional statement.
    $ip = @()

    #loop content and build into array
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $content.Count; $i++)
    { 
        #Get data with only specified elements
        $list = $content[$i] | Select-Object IP, Exploitability , OS , Severity | Where-Object {$_.Severity -eq 5 -or $_.Severity -eq 4 -and $_.OS -like "Windows*" }  

        #Check to see if the variable is not empty.
        if ($list)
        {
            #Look up the IP Address and set in the array variable 
            $ip += [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByAddress($list.ip).HostName.ToString()
        }
    }

    #clean duplicate entries
    $ip = $ip | select -Unique

    #output to a txt file.
    $ip | Out-File c:\List.txt -Append
}

#if cancled, notify the user and wait for a key press
Else
{
    #write a notification to a user
    Write-Host "You have cancled the request.`n `nPress any key to continue...";

    #hold for a key press
    $x = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
}
```